# Django server is not starting after importing custom declared class from a python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, python-import

I have written a custom class in a python file and trying to import it to another file.But once I import the class, django server is not starting after so much time, here is what I am doing ..

```
helper.py
```

```
class GeneriMethod:
   @staticmethod
   def afunc1():
       return "something"
   @staticmethod
   def bfunc2():
       pass
   ....
   ....
```

```
tasks/views.py
```

```
from django_app_name.helper import GenericMethod

generic_obj = GenericMethod()

#method 1 
def tsk_func1():
    #call the imported class methods
    generic_obj.afunc1()

#method 2
def tsk_func2():
    #call the imported class methods
    GenericMethod.afunc1()

After doing this when i do python manage.py runserver , why it is taking too much time like 5-10 minutes to run the server,when i remove the import then it works faster, i have no idea what is going on, please help me to resolve this
```

Comment: why do you use `def` declaration before `class` in `GeneriMethod`?

Comment: sorry i didn't get you, in GeneriMethod , i am declaring static methods , & I want to use these methods in different files

Comment: shouldn't it be `class GeneriMethod` instead of `def class GeneriMethod`?

Comment: opps sorry , its class only , i updated my question